# Is the temperature of an object affected by the motion of the quarks and gluons within the protons and neutrons?

Tags: thermodynamics

Physically seen, temperature is a measure of the average energy per molecule chaotic movement, plus the movement of atoms in molecules.

Now atoms exist of quarks and gluons and they can move pretty fast. But are they also of influence of the temperature of something?

Comment: This similar question may help you: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128867/what-does-temperature-look-like-at-the-subatomic-level

Answer (score 0):

Gluons hold together quarks so strongly in baryons that, although quarks and gluons can vibrate in 3D space and time, *individual* quark and gluon vibrations do not contribute to the [thermodynamic temperature](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html) of matter.

Instead, quarks and gluons add their momentum to atoms and molecules whose vibrations are measured as temperature.  Their mass becomes an input to the formula for thermodynamic temperature, which is the [average kinetic energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/kintem.html) of all the molecules and atoms in an object or a gas.